# mass mail application java versus php

Tags: java, php, sendmail, qmail, massmail

I need to build a mass mail application to send around 20 lacs mail per day. I need some suggestions regarding the technology choice between php and java.
Please suggest.

Comment: Whathaveyoutried.com ? Google might also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either would work.

Java is typically good for bigger projects because it is strongly typed and good for collaboration, but a mass mail application might be simple enough to make that unnecessary.

Most people think of it as easier to do web stuff in PHP, so if you want this to live in a website, you might want to use PHP.

Comment: We are going to make it an application and provide SAS. From your views I guess using java will be better.